# Unexpected behavior of file descriptor and/or I/O streams after running sqlcmd with -i option (read sql from file) in ksh creates infinite loop

Tags: io-redirection, ksh, io, file-descriptors, sqlserver

**Is there a way to use `sqlcmd` with `-i input_file` option without creating an infinite loop in my ksh script?**

- The code reads lines from `$file` and parses it line-by-line to extract data and process other stuff.
- It uses file descriptors redirection to "read the `$file` from the `stdin`".

**Infinite loop code:**

```
exec 3<&0
exec 0<"${file}"
while read -r line || [[ -n ${line} ]]
do
    echo "${line}"
    sqlcmd -S svr -U usr -P pwd -i input_file >/dev/null 2>&1
done
exec 0<&3
exec 3<&-
echo "Script completed successfully!"
```

Output:

```
line 1 ...
line 1 ...
...
line 1 ...^C
```

**Workaround** (use *here document* instead of `-i input_file` option):

```
exec 3<&0
exec 0<"${file}"
while read -r line || [[ -n ${line} ]]
do
    echo "${line}"
    sqlcmd -S svr -U usr -P pwd <<-EOF
        -- SOME SQL CODE HERE
    EOF
    # here document lines are indented with tabs, not whitespaces.
done
exec 0<&3
exec 3<&-
echo "Script completed successfully!"
```

Output:

```
line 1 ...
line 2 ...
line 3 ...
Script completed successfully!
```

Even if there's a workaround for the issue I would like to know what's the reason for that behavior and how to use the `sqlcmd` tool without banning it's `-i input_file` option.

**Notes:**

- Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7 (KornShell).

Comment: Your code should work, though if your ksh does not clear the variable `line` when it reads end-of-file that might cause the problem. It is not clear why you do `read ... || [[ -n $line ]]`. Perhaps you meant `read ... && ...`? Your `sqlcmd` is probably reading stdin. Add `</dev/null` to the `sqlcmd` command.

Comment: Thanks @meuh ! The `sqlcmd` was actually reading from the `stdin` _[facepalm]_ so appending `</dev/null` fixed the problem. Regarding the code `read ... || [[ -n $line ]]`, I use that in case the last line of the file to be read doesn't end with a new line (if the EOF is found in a line with some content, that content will be "discarded"). Refer to this [amazing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12916758/2419789), hope you find it useful.

Comment: Interesting, and complicated, corner case. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @meuh mentioned in the comments, `sqlcmd` was reading **stdin** so appending `</dev/null` fixed the issue. The problem was that the `while` loop was iterating over the **stdin** (previously redirected from a file `exec 0<"${file}"`) and the `sqlcmd` that is inside the `while` attempted to read from the **stdin**. The solution was making the `sqlcmd` to read from `/dev/null` instead of **stdin**.

## Fix

```
exec 3<&0
exec 0<"${file}"
while read -r line || [[ -n ${line} ]]
do
    echo "${line}"
    sqlcmd -S svr -U usr -P pwd -i input_file </dev/null
done
exec 0<&3
exec 3<&-
echo "Script completed successfully!"
```